# Java checking time in a timestamp

Tags: java

Currently I have a timestamp for example say, 2012-06-23 14:24:07.975 and 
two times - 8AM and 3PM.

In java, how can I check whether the above timestamp is between the particular two time.

In other words, I need to check whether the time in timestamp (2012-06-23 **14**:24:07.975) falls between 8AM and 3PM or not.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the timestamp into an actual [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) afterwards you convert it into a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) from where you can extract the hour and check it against your given hours.

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for getting a Date out of your Timestamp, if you cannot directly convert it.. Afterwards

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(yourDate);
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Now do your hour check.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed the same technique. Got 2 dates from the start time (date1) and end time (date2). Then found date3 from the actual time stamp. Then compared the dates as follows:                         boolean status = date1.compareTo(date3) * date3.compareTo(date2) > 0;

Answer (score 1):

`before` and `after` methods should help you to do that. See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

Comment: Thanks used the same methods to compare dates.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `compareTo` method in `Date`.